# automatic partitioning with debian installer preseeding with warning

Tags: installation, debian, partitioning

I want to automate debian installer with debian installer preseeding mechanism (preseed.cfg file). I want installer automatically delete all disk partitions and create one partition for root partition. It is important that installer shows a warning that all partitions will be deleted before operation. how can i do that?

Comment: Wouldn't a warning kind of negate what you are trying to accomplish with this preseeding?

Comment: i want the partitioning step is done without user interaction and automatically but before it a warning should appear to user that all partitions will be deleted

Comment: But how would that work? Should there be a "Press enter to continue before loosing all your data" popup or should it just inform the user that: "All your data is now lost."?

Comment: hmm, I think a warning popup with two buttons first for Continue and second for restart is ok

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Debian documentation you can achieve this with preseeding. Either to inform the user about formatting or just skip that part. Information on this: http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apbs04.html.en

Comment: I've done that by writing new udeb, now I want this preseeding and automation only applies to normal installation not expert install. it means partitioning step in normal installer mode should be automatic and in expert mode should be manual